# Celery expires - Rise exception

Tags: python, celery

In docs [link](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/executing.html#id3) about expires

```
# Task expires after one minute from now.
add.apply_async(args=[10, 10], expires=60)
```

I use:

```
from tasks import add
result = add.apply_async(args=[10, 10], expires=6000)
printus(result)

def printus(result):
    print (result) #task id
    print (result.ready()) # returns True if the task has finished processing.
    print (result.result) # task is not ready, so no return value yet.
    print (result.get())  # Waits until the task is done and returns the retval.
    print (result.result) # direct access to result, doesn't re-raise errors.
    print (result.successful()) # returns True if the task didn't end in failure.)
```

tasks.py

```
from celery.task import task
@task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

In celeryd:

```
[2012-03-21 19:50:03,012: WARNING/MainProcess] Skipping revoked task: tasks.add[4ffcff91-b12b-4bce-8d47-159314759859]
```

In console:

```
4ffcff91-b12b-4bce-8d47-159314759859
True

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/echeg/Dropbox/my_py/opoveshun/tests/celery/run_task.py", line 53, in <module>
    tr.countdown()
  File "/home/echeg/Dropbox/my_py/opoveshun/tests/celery/run_task.py", line 26, in countdown
    self.printus(result)
  File "/home/echeg/Dropbox/my_py/opoveshun/tests/celery/run_task.py", line 48, in printus
    print (result.get())  # Waits until the task is done and returns the retval.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 95, in get
    interval=interval)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 144, in wait_for
    raise self.exception_to_python(meta["result"])
celery.exceptions.TaskRevokedError
```

Why do I get an exception? The result has not expired

If i use:

```
result = add.apply_async(args=[10, 10])
```

all ok

```
226107de-f739-4860-83bc-d843f17a257e
False
None
20
20
True
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

celeryd thinks your task has expired:

```
[2012-03-21 19:50:03,012: WARNING/MainProcess] Skipping revoked task: tasks.add[4ffcff91-b12b-4bce-8d47-159314759859]
```

When an expired task is picked up by a worker, [it revokes it](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#expiration) without executing.  Check your timezone settings?  I had the inverse problem: tasks weren't expiring when they should have.  This fixed it for me:

```
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Etc/UTC'
```